# BroadcastReceiver performing different actions based on Activity running

Tags: android

I'm wondering if there is a way to determine the active activity during the `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` method of a `BroadCastReceiver`? I initially thought that the context passed in was such a way, but later found out that in fact it is a `ReceiverRestrictedContext`.

I'm trying to do the following similar to how one passes information from a `Fragment` to its encapsulating `Activity`:

```
try {
       mListener = (MyListenerInterface) (context.getApplicationContext());
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement MyListenerInterface");
    }

 mListener.onMessageReceived(msg);
```

Each activity implements MyListenerInterface, and overrides the onMessageReceived(msg) method, which I thought would be enough. However, I am receiving the following exception when running and receiving a broadcast:

```
09-24 22:40:48.706: E/AndroidRuntime(29267): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 22:40:48.706: E/AndroidRuntime(29267): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.test.stuff.Receiver: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@448c8008 must implement MyListenerInterface
09-24 22:40:48.706: E/AndroidRuntime(29267):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2821)
09-24 22:40:48.706: E/AndroidRuntime(29267):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-24 22:40:48.706: E/AndroidRuntime(29267):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)
09-24 22:40:48.706: E/AndroidRuntime(29267):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-24 22:40:48.706: E/AndroidRuntime(29267):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-24 22:40:48.706: E/AndroidRuntime(29267):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-24 22:40:48.706: E/AndroidRuntime(29267):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-24 22:40:48.706: E/AndroidRuntime(29267):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-24 22:40:48.706: E/AndroidRuntime(29267):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
09-24 22:40:48.706: E/AndroidRuntime(29267):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-24 22:40:48.706: E/AndroidRuntime(29267):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-24 22:40:48.706: E/AndroidRuntime(29267): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@448c8008 must implement MyListenerInterface
09-24 22:40:48.706: E/AndroidRuntime(29267):    at com.test.stuff.Receiver.onReceive(Receiver.java:63)
09-24 22:40:48.706: E/AndroidRuntime(29267):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2810)
09-24 22:40:48.706: E/AndroidRuntime(29267):    ... 10 more
```

At this point I am just thinking about making an inner class `BroadcastReceiver` in each activity and putting the desired functionality in those, but I am wondering if anyone knows if any work-around to the above scenario where I would only need one `BroadcastReceiver` which would have different functionality based on the running Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At this point I am just thinking about making an inner class `BroadcastReceiver` in each activity and putting the desired functionality in those

Yep, this is the best way to implement that feature.  If you want to make the functionality common rather than copying it into each Activity, you could create a base class for each Activity in the application to extend if you want the `BroadcastReceiver` to be an inner class.

You can also still define it in a separate file as you likely already have, but just register the receiver directly in each Activity rather than once in the AndroidManifest.xml file.  If you register/unregister the receiver in `onResume()`/`onPause()`, then you will still only have one active receiver at any given time which is attached to the currently foreground Activity.  **These methods also keep you from receiving the given broadcast when your app isn't in the foreground at all, whereas a receiver defined in the manifest is always active, forcing you to handle that case.**

If you need to explicitly pass some identifier to each instance of the `BroadcastReceiver` as to which Activity it's associated with, define a simple identifier (like the class name as a String) that you can check in the receiver.  It's not a good idea to pass the Activity itself, for similar reasons as to why the framework doesn't do that either.  If you're curious, I wrote a [blog post](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/) not long ago detailing some of the issues with passing around Context like that.

Comment: Okay, I thought this was the cleanest way to do this. I'm also interested in receiving broadcasts while the application is not in the foreground. What I'm thinking of doing is registering a global `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest, which will send out an appropriate and application specific ordered broadcast, which can get picked up and handled by the running activity. If you have any comments on this let me know, otherwise I will try it out and see which works best.

Comment: Have a look at `LocalBroadcastManager` for the secondary part, it will be more efficient than a global broadcast: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html

Comment: If you only deliver it to the running Activity, making the broadcast ordered is also unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Awesome thanks this is pretty much exactly what I am looking for. Since there is only a maximum of one activity that is active at a time, only one activity will receive the broadcast if the local `BroadcastReceiver` are unregistered in `onPause()`, and registered in `onResume()`. At this point i'm unsure if broadcasts get put in a queue while the receiver is unregistered, but that is something I can figure out fairly quickly. If they aren't, then I have my own queue that I can read in `onResume()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the ActivityManager.getRunningTasks() method? That might help you in your receiver to figure out what's in the foreground.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an `Application`-based class to store your lastActivity. On each `Activity` `onResume` just call `App.setLastActivity`

```
public final class App extends Application {

private static Activity lastActivity = null;
    public static void setLastActivity(Activity activity){
        lastActivity = activity;
    }
    public static Activity getLastActivity(){
        return lastActivity;
    }
}
```

Then whenever you need it - call `getLastActivity` and act according to the value you obtained.

Do not forget to add `Application` class name to `application` tag in the manifest

```
android:name="your.packahe.name.App"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the running activity by following  code

ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

```
     List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1); 

     Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::"
             + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());
```

By comparing classname of your activity with `taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName()` you can implement different functionalities.